# Launch ZAP using a script if not already running

Tags: python, owasp, zap

I launch ZAP with a Python script using subprocess:

```
filePath=r"C:\\Program Files\\OWASP\\Zed Attack Proxy\\zap-2.11.1.jar"
subprocess.Popen(filePath, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This script works fine and launches ZAP. However, I'd like to have a check whether the app is already running and if so, not to launch it again. I took a look how could this be achieved in Python and realized I could use a check for running processes. Problem is that the process runs as Java(TM) Platform SE binary in Task Manager so checking for that one might not be the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple workaround would be to simply grab all titles of current processes and if it happens to find zap amongst them then break

or just have a flag set if it finds it as follows:

```
import subprocess
import pyautogui
global marker
marker = False

for window in pyautogui.getAllWindows():  
    if window.title == "OWASP ZAP":
        marker = True
if marker:
    filePath=r"C:\\Program Files\\OWASP\\Zed Attack Proxy\\zap-2.11.1.jar"
    subprocess.Popen(filePath, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your reply. this indeed looks as a good workaround at first sight (though the flag should be marked the other way around, should be set to True on initialization and to False if window.title found, also window.title is 'OWASP ZAP - OWASP ZAP (version number)' so i updated that one as well. what happens though if i try and run ZAP in daemon mode? i assume this solution wouldn't work anymore?

Comment: okay, it seems to work in daemon mode as well. thanks for your help!